# Módulo operator invoca métodos especiais dos objetos

Tags: python, python-3.x, operadores, módulo-python

A `biblioteca padrão do Python` possui o módulo `operator`, estudando o mesmo notei que algumas de suas funções possuem digamos `"aliases"`, por exemplo:

```
operator.setitem(a, b, c)
operator.__setitem__(a, b, c)
Set the value of a at index b to c.
```

Para entender melhor o módulo criei meu próprio objeto pra verificar o comportamento do mesmo com as chamados do módulo.

```
class Spam:

   def __add__(self, other):
       print('call __add__')


>>> operator.add(Spam(), 3)
"call __add__"
>>> operator.__add__(Spam(), 3) 
"call __add__"
```

Como podem `operator.add` e `operator.__add__` chamam o mesmo método especial. Minhas dúvidas são:

- Existe diferença entre os `métodos(sem dunders)` e os `métodos
  dunders`. Exemplo:`operator.setitem(a, b, c)` e
  `operator.__setitem__(a, b, c)`?
- Como vimos alguns do `métodos do módulo` `operator` fazem chamadas a
  `métodos internos do objeto` caso o mesmo tenha sido definido. Mas
  sinceramente não sei porquê, sou levado a acreditar que quando
  fazemos uma operação por exemplo de soma, é de alguma forma invocado
  `operator.add`(ou `operator.__add__`), estou errado?

Comment: Para quem interessar, código fonte do módulo `operator`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/operator.py#L420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Existe diferença entre os métodos(sem dunders) e os métodos dunders.
>   Exemplo:operator.setitem(a, b, c) e `operator.__setitem__(a, b, c)`?

Provavelmente não tem diferença nenhuma - (como está na outra resposta, são apenas aliases mesmo). 
A recomendação no entanto é: deixar a linguagem chamar internamente os nomes com "dunder", e, ao fazer chamadas explícitas, usar sempre o nome sem dunder - quando houver.

> Como vimos alguns do métodos do módulo operator fazem chamadas a métodos internos do objeto caso o mesmo tenha sido definido. Mas
>   sinceramente não sei porquê, sou levado a acreditar que quando fazemos
>   uma operação por exemplo de soma, é de alguma forma invocado
>   operator.add(ou `operator.__add__`), estou errado?

na verdade, é o contrário  - em Python, cada classe define como os objetos vão se comportar com os operadores - isso é, a linguagem permite "operator overriding". A forma como isso é feito pela linguagem está descrita no documento chamado [Data Model na documentação da linguagem.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) . Em suma - os métodos dunder **na classe** é que contém o código que será executado quando instâncias daquela classe estiverem envolvidas com o uso de operadores, ou outras ações que envolvam os métodos "dunder".

É fácil verificar que o fluxo é esse ao se tentar imaginar o contrário: se o "código específico" para o *add* de cada classe estivesse em "poder" do `operator.add`, e não em cada classe, onde é que os desenvolvedores colocariam o código para o operador `operator.add` usar? Ou mesmo pensando no código já existente - será que teria sentido o código de `operator.add` centralizar tanto o código para a adição de sequências (que é concatenação)  e de números (adição)?

Então o caminho é o contrário  - o módulo `operator` é um "nice to have", mas de forma alguma essencial em qualquer programa Python.

Na prática, ele é apenas uma forma de manter justamente a regra - mais de estilo do que de necessidade - de "você não precisa chamar os métodos 'dunder' diretamente". Assim, você pode escrever `operator.neg(b)` em vez de `b.__neg__()`. (Para operadores binários, as funções em operator fazem um pouco mais - por que implementam também a lógica de chamar a soma reversa - `__radd__`, no segundo objeto de uma operação, se a soma entre os tipos de objeto da expressão não estiver implementada no primeiro objeto).

Tanto é que ele contém os operadores matemáticos e outros com sintaxe própria na linguagem - cujo uso mais comum é em expressões que ficam fixas no programa (isso é - é mais comum você escrever `a = b + c` do que `a = add(b, c)`). No entanto, alguns métodos dunder que não possuem sintaxe especial, tem a chamada equivalente às que estão no módulo `operator` direto como built-in da linguagem - por exemplo, as funções `len` e `hash` que chamam respectivamente os métodos `__len__` e `__hash__`

Um dos usos que o módulo `operator` tem é quando, no momento em que você escreve um tipo de código, não sabe ainda que operação vai ser executada entre dois operandos - por exemplo, um programa de calculadora pode verificar se o usuário digitou "-" ou "+" para escolher "operator.add" ou "operator.sub" programaticamente, de forma mais elegante que uma sequência de `if`s em que a expressão é repetida toda vez:

Em vez de:

```
if operacao == "+":
    a = b + c
elif operacao == "-":
    a = b - c
...
```

é possível escrever algo do tipo:

```
operacoes = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, ...}
a = operacores[operacao](b, c)
```

e dito tudo isso, alguns membros do módulo "operator" ainda fazem algo mais - por exemplo, o `itemgetter`, `attrgetter` e `methodcaller` retornam um objeto chamável (que pode ser chamado como se fosse uma função), reutilizável, que pode ser usado com vários objetos diferentes na criação de código bastante elegante.

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 0):

São a mesma coisa. Olha o código da biblioteca a partir da linha 248: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/operator.py

```
# All of these "__func__ = func" assignments have to happen after importing
# from _operator to make sure they're set to the right function
...
__abs__ = abs
__add__ = add
__and__ = and_
```

Você pode fazer a mesma coisa:

```
class Spam:
    def __add__(self, other):
        print('call __add__')
    add = __add__

s = Spam()
print(Spam.__add__ == Spam.add)
print(s.__add__ == s.add)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou utilizar a explicação do livro Fluent Python do Ramalho:

A Primeira coisa a saber sobre os métodos especias é que eles foram criados para serem chamados pelo interpretador Python, e não por voce. Não escrevemos `my_object.__len__()`. Escrevemos `len(my_object)` e, se `my_object` for uma instancia de uma classe definida por voce, Python chamará o método de instancia `__len__` que voce implementou.

Porém, para os tipos embutidos (built-in) como `list, str, bytearray` e outros, o interpretador usará um atalho: a implementação de `len()` do CPython, na verdade, retorna o valor do campo `ob_size` da struct C `PyVarobject` que representa qq objeto embutido de tamanho variável na memória. Isso é muito mais rápido que chamar um método.

Na maioria das vezes a chamada ao método especial será implicita. Por exemplo a instrução `for i in x:` provoca a chamada de `iter(x)`, que por sua vez poderá chamar `x.__iter__()` se ele estiver disponível.

Se vc não estiver usando bastante metaprogramação, seu código não deverá ter chamadas aos metodos ditos especiais.

O único método especial chamado diretamente pelo usuário de forma frequente é o `__init__` para invocar o inicializador da superclasse qdo o usuario implementa o proprio `__init__`.

Por ultimo e não menos importante, evite criar atributos com a sintaxe `__foo__`, pois no futuro estes nomes poderão adquirir signficados especiais, mesmo que não estiverem em uso atualmente.

> Editada

Sobre a chamada do __init__ no livro do Luciano:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde que o `__init__` é chamado "direto pelo usuário"? :-) Ele é justamente um bom exemplo de que o Python é que chama os métodos "dunder" - você instancia a classe com a sintaxe normal de "chamar um objeto" - com os parenteses com parâmetros depois do nome do objeto, e o Python é que chama o `__init__`. 

O que é diferente no `__init__` em relação aos outros é sim que na maior parte do código Python que se escreve, ele é o único método duner que você precisa escrever - a não ser que esteja criando classes de base com comportamento personalizado.

Comment: @jsbueno, como eu disse no inicio do texto, peguei diretamente do livro do Ramalho, pensando bem depois que vc observou eu tb fiquei na duvida, precisaria ver com ele se foi um erro da edição ou ele quis dizer algo que não ficou claro.

Comment: Se a frase for essa mesmo, ela realmente está equivocada nesse contexto. Tenho uma cópia desse livro, vou checar aqui - sabe se tem algum fórum/endereço que o Ramalho reservou pra envio de erratas? No texto geral, isso seria uma coisa pequena, mas se ele está aceitando pequenas correções para as próximas edições vale a pena apontar isso sim.

Comment: Ja "conversei" com ele via email, inclusive sobre uma questão aqui no STO, ele foi bem receptivo, o email dele: luciano@ramalho.org.  Chequei aqui na versão em portugues em papel, a frase é exatamente essa. Vou scanear e editar minha resp.

Comment: Legal - acho que é o que comentei acima mesmo: a diferença para o `__init__` é que o programador tem que se preocupar em implementa-lo com mais frequência  - mas nem por isso ele é chamado explicitamente. Pode falar pra ele que eu que comentei.

Comment: Você tem que chamar explicitamente o `__init__` quando você faz o seu próprio `__init__` em uma subclasse e quer chamar o `__init__` da classe pai... Geralmente assim: `super().__init__(...)` - é isso que o autor do livro quis dizer. Mesmo assim é um pouco estranho porque o mesmo pode ser dito para qualquer método que você queira sobrescrever na classe filha, tendo dunder ou não.